# Django models making with multiple condition

Tags: django, django-models

I am developing an app for cinema show seat booking and going through a trouble to design my `models`

this is my current models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Seats(models.Model):
    seat_choice = (
        ('AA', 'AA'),
        ('AB', 'AB'),
        ('BA', 'BA'),
        ('BB', 'BB'),
        ('CA', 'CA'),
        ('CB', 'CB')
    )
    name = models.CharField(choices=seat_choice, max_length=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Show(models.Model):
    show_choice  = (
        ('MORNING', 'MORNING'),
        ('NIGN', 'NIGHT'),
    )
    show_schedule = models.CharField(choices=show_choice, max_length=10)
    movie = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Booking(models.Model):
    seat = models.OneToOneField(Seats, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    show = models.ForeignKey(Show, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'booking_booking'
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['seat', 'show'], name='unique booking')
        ]
```

I am trying to achieve  like If a seat booked of a show, it can't be booked again later but it can be booked by later for another show.

But my current models problem is: If i book a seat for a show, i cant book the same seat for another show (which is i dont want)

My Requirement is simple: If i book a seat for a show, later i should able to book the same seat for another different show but it cant be booked again for the same show...

I know i can achieve it removing the show and using created like below:

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    seat = models.OneToOneField(Seats, unique_for_date='created', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

But i dont want like this. I need to keep the show field at any means...

Comment: I can't see anything that will prevent you from booking the same seat for another show in your code. Is there anything that you don't show us?

Comment: you just need to check if any booking with particular seat_id and show_id exists.

Comment: @selcuk I edited, please check

Comment: @nalin, how can do like you suggested? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you can only have one booking per `Seat` because of your `OneToOne` relation:

```
class Booking(models.Model):
     seat = models.OneToOneField(Seats, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Change it to a `ForeignKey` so that one `Seat` can be associated with multiple `Booking`s:

```
 seat = models.ForeignKey(Seats, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```